# Finding Faces Of Non-Convex Polyhedron

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose that the you have a polyhedron, $P$, which is not convex with $N$ vertices,  $O(N)$ faces, and $O(N)$ edges. You are given the vertices of the polyhedron along with the edges incident on each vertex.

Is there a way to find all faces of $P$ in $O(N)$ time?

Comment: In what sense do you "have" the polyhedron? You need some description of it. As currently phrased, your problem is underspecified.

Comment: I added what information you are given about the polyhedron

Comment: Maybe look at the MO question "[Reporting all faces in a planar graph](http://mathoverflow.net/q/23811/6094)" and see if that clarifies.